# How to display an icon in a menu item?

Tags: python, menu, gtk, pygtk, menuitem

I know how to create a plain text menu item:

```
item = gtk.MenuItem('text')
```

but how can I display an icon?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `ImageMenuItem` instead of `MenuItem`.

Here's an example: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/menus/